# maxout activation in classification s-o-a networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I find that maxout activation is not so used in state of the art deep convolutional networks, at least for image classification (e.g. VGG networks, ResNet); is this correct? If so, is there a specific reason for that?

Using maxout increases the model size compared to ReLU, then I assume it does not always lead to accuracy improvements but it could be more dependent on the problem to be solved

Comment: I think the downvote was due to incomplete title when I first created the question: if so please correct this; otherwise let me know how would you improve the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the activation function you choose for your network has mostly to do with convergence times, avoiding "dead neurons" (when the output of the linear unit is always negative and hence the relu's output always 0) and computation costs.

The relu activation function is computationally cheaper than maxout so maybe that is why it is used in convolutional networks which are already expensive as they are.

Comment: According to results in the [maxout paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4389.pdf), maxout activation performs better than ReLU in different configurations (see Fig.6).
If maxout performs better than ReLU in general, then I don't understand why not using it even if it makes the model more complex when the target is highest accuracy

Comment: Without some cross validation with mean and standard deviations for those error values I would have a hard time saying that maxout performs better than relu (perhaps the performance increase is statistically irrelevant). But assuming it did it can be because relu caused "dead neurons" effectively decreasing the networks capacity compared to maxout. If you were to increase the networks capacity the start maybe you would see different results.

Comment: If maxout provides a better use of model capacity I still not have a clear answer to my question: then I think one should have a significantly larger model (in terms of ReLU units) to achieve same performance level. 
Assuming performance increase is statistically irrelevant, what in your opinion would be the benefit from maxout activation?

Comment: Even though it provides model more capacity it is at the expense of complexity and run time. I don't think the model using relu's must be significantly larger, in the paper using the same architecture it performs marginally worse. I don't know if the performance increase is statistically irrelevant because the paper does not provide enough information to answer that.

Comment: To get back to question why is maxout not more widespread, I think a combination of the tradition of using relu's; a performance gain not big enough and in my view still needing some proof; and the existence of other activation functions that address the same issues as maxout such as the prelu (which is not has computationally expensive).